# why Spring-data-jpa didnot save the subclass object?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

The reason for this problem is a configuration. Hibernate have a configuration: hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size, so I just added it in application.properties as: *spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size*(wrong), however you cannot find it in Appendix A. Common application properties.  It  works for me by deleting this property.

finally, why springboot didnot throw a execption, if he cannot understand this property? Why this error property can interference the commit of transaction?

update2 hibernate sql log
Update1 user and student classes code.

By the way, it was an old project and worked fine with spring 5.0.4 and JPA2.1(Hibernate 5.2.14). I am studying and trying to migrate this project to springboot and spring-data-jpa.

I had a very very weird problem. When I am trying to persit a subclass object to database, spring data jpa can only persist the superclass properties into superclass table, but nothing in the subclass table. And if persist two subclass object at one time, the first object can be saved to subclass table, but the second will be Ignored. However, the insert sql statement seem to be executed(at least it showed in the console).

spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.1.0

superclass

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Data
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String number;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    @ManyToOne
    private Authority authority;
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm")
    private LocalDateTime insertTime;
    }
```

subclass

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Student extends User{
    private String clazz;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @OrderBy(value ="id ASC")
    private Set<CourseDetail> courseDetails;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    @OrderBy(value ="id ASC")
    private Set<ExperimentDetail> experimentDetails;
}
```

StudentRepository

```
@Repository
    public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {}
```

Service

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Slf4j
public class TestService {
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRep;
    public void addStudentTest() {
        Student s = new Student();
        s.setName("1");
        s.setClazz("1");
        studentRep.save(s);

        Student s1 = new Student();
        s1.setName("2");
        s1.setClazz("2");
        studentRep.save(s1);
        // int a = 1 / 0;
           log.debug(String.valueOf(TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName()));
}
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Slf4j
public class AddUserTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestService testService;
    @Test
    public void addStudentTest() {
        testService.addStudentTest();

    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coursetest?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=GMT%2B8&characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Console

```
Hibernate: insert into user (authority_id, insert_time, name, number, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (clazz, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (authority_id, insert_time, name, number, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (clazz, id) values (?, ?)
2018-12-23 13:39:19 DEBUG com.se.courses.service.TestService.addStudentTest[43] - com.se.courses.service.TestService.addStudentTest
```

user table: https://i.ibb.co/MG0cNkF/01.png

student table: https://i.ibb.co/0qwv7R2/02.png

Why the console has outputted the insert student SQL statement twice, but user id=3 record not be inserted into the student table?? please help me.

add new loging properties

```
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace

2018-12-24 00:53:19 DEBUG org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarting[53] - Running with Spring Boot v2.1.0.RELEASE, Spring v5.1.2.RELEASE
2018-12-24 00:53:19 INFO  org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupProfileInfo[675] - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table authority (id bigint not null auto_increment, insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table authority (id bigint not null auto_increment, insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, name varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table course (id bigint not null auto_increment, insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, name varchar(255), teacher_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table course (id bigint not null auto_increment, insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, name varchar(255), teacher_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table course_detail (id bigint not null auto_increment, insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, course_id bigint, student_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table course_detail (id bigint not null auto_increment, insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, course_id bigint, student_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table experiment (id bigint not null auto_increment, file_extension varchar(255), insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, name varchar(255), course_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table experiment (id bigint not null auto_increment, file_extension varchar(255), insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, name varchar(255), course_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table experiment_detail (id bigint not null auto_increment, complete_time TIMESTAMP, file varchar(255), experiment_id bigint, student_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table experiment_detail (id bigint not null auto_increment, complete_time TIMESTAMP, file varchar(255), experiment_id bigint, student_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table homework (id bigint not null auto_increment, content varchar(255), insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, title varchar(255), course_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table homework (id bigint not null auto_increment, content varchar(255), insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, title varchar(255), course_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table homework_detail (id bigint not null auto_increment, complete_time TIMESTAMP, solution TEXT, homework_id bigint, student_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table homework_detail (id bigint not null auto_increment, complete_time TIMESTAMP, solution TEXT, homework_id bigint, student_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table student (clazz varchar(255), id bigint not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table student (clazz varchar(255), id bigint not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table teacher (id bigint not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table teacher (id bigint not null, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - create table user (id bigint not null auto_increment, insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, name varchar(255), number varchar(255), password varchar(255), authority_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
Hibernate: create table user (id bigint not null auto_increment, insert_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, name varchar(255), number varchar(255), password varchar(255), authority_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table user drop index UK_32852vmffyhhg5ov56amkcx7s
Hibernate: alter table user drop index UK_32852vmffyhhg5ov56amkcx7s
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table user add constraint UK_32852vmffyhhg5ov56amkcx7s unique (number)
Hibernate: alter table user add constraint UK_32852vmffyhhg5ov56amkcx7s unique (number)
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table course add constraint FKsybhlxoejr4j3teomm5u2bx1n foreign key (teacher_id) references teacher (id)
Hibernate: alter table course add constraint FKsybhlxoejr4j3teomm5u2bx1n foreign key (teacher_id) references teacher (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table course_detail add constraint FKonm6feulb9dmgri1ywpvid8l2 foreign key (course_id) references course (id)
Hibernate: alter table course_detail add constraint FKonm6feulb9dmgri1ywpvid8l2 foreign key (course_id) references course (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table course_detail add constraint FKdh9dl501ehcfblljjpmx28sya foreign key (student_id) references student (id)
Hibernate: alter table course_detail add constraint FKdh9dl501ehcfblljjpmx28sya foreign key (student_id) references student (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:22 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table experiment add constraint FK68ee92hji28v7m63lcbe49mxm foreign key (course_id) references course (id)
Hibernate: alter table experiment add constraint FK68ee92hji28v7m63lcbe49mxm foreign key (course_id) references course (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:23 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table experiment_detail add constraint FKtg40ugg4gkd1raph37jfjpko9 foreign key (experiment_id) references experiment (id)
Hibernate: alter table experiment_detail add constraint FKtg40ugg4gkd1raph37jfjpko9 foreign key (experiment_id) references experiment (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:23 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table experiment_detail add constraint FKqxlpw83x0k6mpn4401oiqosil foreign key (student_id) references student (id)
Hibernate: alter table experiment_detail add constraint FKqxlpw83x0k6mpn4401oiqosil foreign key (student_id) references student (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:23 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table homework add constraint FKaippn77cl5hhh944no78eone8 foreign key (course_id) references course (id)
Hibernate: alter table homework add constraint FKaippn77cl5hhh944no78eone8 foreign key (course_id) references course (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:23 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table homework_detail add constraint FK6w6svv21e1qib443omjcn6u4w foreign key (homework_id) references homework (id)
Hibernate: alter table homework_detail add constraint FK6w6svv21e1qib443omjcn6u4w foreign key (homework_id) references homework (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:23 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table homework_detail add constraint FKjqmtghar9welw7yyoan5n1516 foreign key (student_id) references student (id)
Hibernate: alter table homework_detail add constraint FKjqmtghar9welw7yyoan5n1516 foreign key (student_id) references student (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:23 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table student add constraint FKqytew32213tbnj8u0er377k3q foreign key (id) references user (id)
Hibernate: alter table student add constraint FKqytew32213tbnj8u0er377k3q foreign key (id) references user (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:23 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table teacher add constraint FKlicv62vmu1ydw117bbxqhkof1 foreign key (id) references user (id)
Hibernate: alter table teacher add constraint FKlicv62vmu1ydw117bbxqhkof1 foreign key (id) references user (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:23 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - alter table user add constraint FKokrgxdbtf7tirfx1d1qtg9n24 foreign key (authority_id) references authority (id)
Hibernate: alter table user add constraint FKokrgxdbtf7tirfx1d1qtg9n24 foreign key (authority_id) references authority (id)
2018-12-24 00:53:24 WARN  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration.openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor[234] - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2018-12-24 00:53:25 INFO  org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarted[59] - Started AddUserTest in 6.043 seconds (JVM running for 6.775)
2018-12-24 00:53:25 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - insert into user (authority_id, insert_time, name, number, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (authority_id, insert_time, name, number, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[53] - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[53] - binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[65] - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[53] - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[53] - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - insert into student (clazz, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (clazz, id) values (?, ?)
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[65] - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [1]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[65] - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - insert into user (authority_id, insert_time, name, number, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into user (authority_id, insert_time, name, number, password) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[53] - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [null]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[53] - binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [null]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[65] - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [2]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[53] - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[53] - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement[94] - insert into student (clazz, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into student (clazz, id) values (?, ?)
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[65] - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [2]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind[65] - binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [2]
2018-12-24 00:53:25 DEBUG com.se.courses.service.TestService.addStudentTest[39] - com.se.courses.service.TestService.addStudentTest
```

Comment: Can you please show the full user and student classes with all the mapping?

Comment: User and student classes code been updated. Thanks for you help

Comment: Try to add the annotations  Transactional and Commit to your test method and see what's happen

Comment: Thank you, already did, not work. I even created the CustomizedRepoistory inject the entitymanager, and use original JPA method persist() to persist the 2 subclass objects, still didnot work.

Comment: I tried your code and everything works for me. Can you add these two loggers: logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql=trace and post the output

Comment: It worked in a new clear project!! I will try to find out WHY and close this issue. Thanks Simon, thanks for your patient and help! :)